# Java without Java (not just a koan)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, java

I noticed my Ubuntu server was bumping against its RAM limit and using its swap despite not doing a whole heck of a lot, so I checked top and the first thing I noticed was that Java, run by root, was using 25% of my memory.

So I ran apt-cache rdepends to see what was using java, and it turns out I don't have a java package installed. Java -version returns command not found. Whereis returns /usr/share/java, which contains only gettext.jar and libintl.jar.

So for kicks, I term'd that process. It's been half an hour now and the system seems stable, nothing has stopped working, and I suddenly have a lot of extra memory and no swap usage.

Is there any way to determine what started that process and why? Where is that coming from? Why is it taking up almost a gig of RAM?